# $P,Q$ Sylow subgroups $\implies$ $PQ$ a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

$|G|<+\infty$, $p\not=q$ primes, $n_p=p+1$, $n_q=q+1$.

I want to show that $\exists P\in Syl_p(G), Q\in Syl_q(G)$ s.t. $PQ=P\times Q<G.$

I understand this exercise as to show that $PQ$ is a subgroup.

If one of tham is normal, then the statement is trivial. However, neither $n_p$ nor $n_q$ is $1$, we don't know the normalities of $P$ and $Q$.

The main problem is showing the closedness of the operation: $a=p_1q_1, b=p_2q_2.$ $ab=p_1q_1p_2q_2\in PQ?$

From the Sylow theorems, I've got some facts like $$|G|=p^nq^mA\implies p+1|q^mA,\ q+1|p^nA$$ but how to connect them to the closedness.

Comment: What is order of the group $G$. Is it $p^nq^m$?

Comment: @S.D. it's finite, no other restrictions.

Comment: If you are not saying group generated by $P$ and $Q$ then result is false

Comment: “So we don’t know the normality of $P$ and $Q$”. Actually, we *do* know: they are **not** normal. Neither of them. A Sylow $p$-Subgroup is normal if and only if it is the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: @MANI Yes, the subgroup is generated by $P$ and $Q$ and is equal to $PQ$

Comment: Assuming $p\lt q$, if we don’t have $p=2$ and $q=3$, then any Sylow $q$-subgroup acts by conjugation on the set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups, giving a homomorphism into $S_{p+1}$, which must therefore be trivial since $S_{p+1}$ doe snot have elements of order $q$. So in this case, for any Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ and any Sylow $q$-Subgroup $Q$, $Q\leq N_G(P)$, so $QP=PQ$ is a subgroup. Haven’t finished the $p=2$ and $q=3$ case.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you explain more about "any Sylow $q$-subgroup acts by conjugation on the set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups, giving a homomorphism into $S_{p+1}$"?

Comment: If a group $H$ acts on a set $X$ with $k$ elements, then the action induces a homomorphism from $H$ to $S_k$. The group $G$ acts by conjugation on the set of all its Sylow $p$-subgroups, and the restriction of that action from $G$ to $Q$ gives an action of $Q$ on a set with $p+1$ elements, hence a homomorphism from $Q$ to $S_{p+1}$.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. By the 2nd Sylow theorem, $Q<G$ acts on $Syl_p(G)$ by conjugation. From this, let $\phi(q):=\pi_q.\ (Q\to S_{p+1})$ such that $\pi_q(P):=q^{-1}Pq=P'\in Syl_p(G)$. But $2<p<q$ so $\pi_q=\pi_e$ for all $q\in Q$. $\implies q^{-1}Pq=e^{-1}Pe=P$ for all $q\in Q\implies Q<N_G(P).$

Comment: And for $p=2$ and $q=3$ case, $|Syl_p(G)|=|Syl_2(G)|=n_2=3\implies Syl_2(G)=\mathbb{Z_3}$, and none of the elements of it has order $3$.

Comment: The last part is wrong. $n_2=3$ does not mean that the Sylow $2$ subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (that’s nonsense!) It means there are *three* distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups. In fact, because $n_3=4$ and divides $|G|$, you know that the Sylow $2$-subgroups have order at least $4$.

Comment: I reached the same point Arturo did. Unless $p$ and $q$ are $2$ and $3$, we can find $P$ and $Q$ such that one normalizes the other. The claim does not hold for arbitrary $(P,Q)$ pair, we need to exercise some care. I don't have the time to think about it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must assume $\{p,q\} \neq \{2,3\}$ (see counterexample of Jyrki below - $S_4$).

Suppose $p \lt q$, let $P \in Syl_p(G)$. By assumption $|G : N_G(P)| = p + 1$. If $q \mid (p + 1)$, then $q \gt p$ yields $q = p + 1$ and $\{ p, q \}  = \{ 2, 3 \}$, contradiction.

Hence $q$ does not divide $p + 1$ and $N_G(P)$ contains a full Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$. Thus $H = PQ$ is a subgroup of $G$, with $P \lhd H$. The number of Sylow $q$-subgroups of $H$ is $\equiv 1$  mod $q$ and at most the number in $G$. Thus either $Q \lhd H$ or $H$ has $q + 1$ Sylow $q$-subgroups.

In the latter case, since
$|H : Q| = |P|$ is a power of $p$, we obtain $q+1 = p^a$, so $q = p^a −1 = (p−1)(p^{a-1} + \cdots +1)$.
Since $q$ is prime, $p \neq 2$ and $q \gt p$, this is a contradiction. Thus both $P$ and $Q$ are normal in $H$, whence $H=P \times Q$.

Comment: Nice. Supplementing this with the (well known) example of $G=S_4$ that has $3+1$ Sylow 3-subgroups and $2+1$ Sylow $2$-subgroups. We actually still have $G=PQ$, so $PQ$ is a subgroup. But their product is not direct. It is not even a semi-direct product as $S_4$ has no normal Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Actually. In your last paragraph we also seem to have the possibility that $p=2$ and $q$ is a Mersenne prime, don't we?

Comment: Jyrki, I think you are right! Hence oops! If $a=2$ and $p=2$, then $q=3$ which is not $\equiv 1$ mod $3$. So the question remains if we can find a counterexample of a group with $p=2$ and $q=2^a-1$ prime ($a$ prime, $a \gt 2$) with $n_p=3$ and $n_q=2^a$. Alternatively, we could also relax the condition by demanding that $p$ is odd.

Comment: "Hence $q$ does not divide $p+1$ and $N_G(P)$ contains a full Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$." could you explain more on this implication? Does $q$ not dividing $p+1$ directly imply that $Q$, and all of the other Sylow $q$-subgroups are inside $N_G(P)$? Or did you use the induced homomorphism to symmetric group $S_{p+1}$?

Comment: In general, if $q$ is a prime dividing $|G|$ and  $H \leq G$ with $gcd(|G:H|, q)=1$, then $|H|$ is divisible by the *highest* power of $q$ dividing $|G|$ right? So, applying Sylow theory inside $H$, we can find a $Q \in Syl_q(H)$ and necessarily $Q \in Syl_q(G)$. Clear now?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, rethinking this after many years, if $G$ is a finite group with $n_p=p+1$ for all primes $p$ dividing $|G|$, what can be said about $G$? Must it be solvable? If $|G|=p^aq^b$ with $p,q \notin \{2,3\}$ $G$ is even nilpotent. Your example $S_4$ shows a solvable one. But what about $|G|$ being divisible by more than two primes?